# Creating fluent api issue

Tags: c#

I'm playing around with creating a fluent api. For my learning, I'm just going to stub out a simple rest client.

What I've got so far is this:

```
public interface IOAuthAuthentication
{
    void AddParameter(string name, string value);
}

public interface IRestClient
{
    IRestClient WithBasicAuthentication(string username, string password);
    IRestClient WithNetworkAuthentication(string username, string password);
    IOAuthAuthentication WithOAuthAuthentication(Uri authorizationUrl, string clientId, string clientSecret);
}

public class RestClient : IRestClient
{
    public RestClient(Uri root)
    {
    }

    public IRestClient WithBasicAuthentication(string username, string password)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IRestClient WithNetworkAuthentication(string username, string password)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IOAuthAuthentication WithOAuthAuthentication(Uri authorizationUrl, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I kind of imagined using it like this:

```
        IRestClient restClient = new RestClient(new Uri(""))
                                    .WithBasicAuthentication("", "")
                                    .WithNetworkAuthentication("", "")
                                    .WithOAuthAuthentication(new Uri(""), "", "")
                                        .AddParameter("", "");
```

Now, obviously, you wouldn't have 3 different authentication methods, but that would be handled in the methods themselves I suppose.

For the OAuth authentication, the user might need to add a custom parameter, so I defined a different return type... however, this has the side affect of you can't end the chain with `WithOAuthAuthentication()` or `.AddParameter()`.

What's the correct way to handle that in fluent? I've seen some .net core stuff and was maybe thinking off something like:

```
WithOAuthAuthentication("", "", "", x => x.AddParameter("", ""))
```

and have the `WithOAuthAuthentication()` return IRestClient.

Would that be more "fluenty"?

But then the code doesn't look as cool if you have to add a bunch of params:

```
.WithOAuthAuthentication("", "", "", x =>
{
   x.AddParameter("", "")
    .AddParameter("", "")
});
```

Comment: `For the OAuth authentication, the user might need to add a custom parameter, so I defined a different return type` -- I don't understand what you mean.  For Fluent Interfaces, the return type of a method is always going to be `this`.  You'll have to work within that constraint.

Comment: @RobertHarvey -- what I mean is.. with OAuth authentication, the user might need to add stuff specific to that authentication method... AddParameter() doesn't apply to the other types... so does it make sense to put it in RestClient? Then the user could just blindly call the method without it even making sense.

Comment: You probably want that to be a `new OAuth(something)` somewhere in your fluent calls, then.

Comment: You could do what ASP.NET Core Identity does. It returns you an `ISomething` that's not the `IServiceCollection` used by the .NET Core Fluent Interface

Comment: @RobertHarvey looking at some .net core code, it seems like they do my last example where they just have the outer object return this and include a Action / Func lambda if you need to set stuff specific to that... is that fluent or more of a .net core thing?

Comment: "Fluent Interface" means you `return this` to allow method chaining, and that's all it really is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Fluent means you ```return this``` ?  That is not always the case.  ```items.Where(x => x...).OrderBy(x => x...)…``` ```Where``` returns ```IEnumerable<TSource>``` and ```OrderBy``` returns ```IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>```.  Fluent just means you can chain the calls in a logical readable fashion.  The end result may even be void.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII: You're right. I was trying to make a different point.  The return type is the anchor for the next call, and Linq gets into some other issues like extension methods.  Note the use of `return this` in the OP's code.

Comment: To build a Fluent API you have to consider types that may change based on usage.  In this example you may start with a ```IRestClient``` but return an ```IRestClientChain``` (or something) where that type is extended with the proper function that allows you to use the ```AddParameter``` responsibly.  Much like I've mentioned with the ```OrderBy``` feature in linq.  It returns a different type for that occasion so that you can chain ordering... For example; ```IOrderedEnumerable``` has the ```ThenBy``` logic added which can only be used in the chain after the first call to ```OrderBy```.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII - yeah, with linq, the return type sometimes mutates which is fine... in the case of a rest interface, I'm not sure I want to add a ".First()" type ending since that'll make it a pain to use. Shawn's answer should do the trick.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  Well; I knew what you were thinking and typically returning ```this``` can work on the proper type but some Fluent API's build types just for chaining.  The Fluent API architecture shouldn't be achieved with any single type.  That can become a large type with unnecessary logic / methods that don't relate the type itself.  When writing Fluent you still want to follow SOLID principles.  Don't overextend your type be Fluent yet return types that allow it to be Fluent.

Comment: @SledgeHammer You're correct.  I wasn't arguing you should do it like Linq; I was using it as an example of Fluent.  The idea is to daisy chain calls so that you can perform multiple actions that read and work as they read.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII - Yup, agreed. These methods are for setting up the rest client on a global basis, so they should be chainable. For something like restClient.GetRequest(…) that'll obviously return an IRequest of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty subjective question, because there are a lot of styles of Fluent APIs out there. Some may even be fine with mutation of the `this` context in which case you could use a Begin/End pattern for your OAuth and between those two method calls would be a mutated version of `this` that is your custom OAuth provider.

If it were me, I would modify your base method signature to:

```
public IRestClient WithOAuthAuthentication(Action<IOAuthAuthentication> oauthHandler)
{
    oauthHandler?.Invoke(new OAuthAuthentication(this));

    return this;
}
```

Then I would see your usage pattern looking something like this:

```
restClient.WithOAuthAuthentication(
    oauth =>
    {
        oauth.SetEndpoint("https://www.example.com")
             .AddParameter("Param1", "CoolValue")
             .AddParameter("Param2", "CoolValue2")
             .Authenticate();
    }
)
.YourNextFluentAction();
```

Comment: This is also called "Hadouken" style, because chaining them like this is very similar to Lisp coding style and their pyramide functions =)  https://www.google.com/search?q=hadouken+coding&tbm=isch

Comment: Thanks... I'll probably go the action route since that's all over the place in .net core it seems, but probably keep the uri, username, password as params and add an overload for the optional action since that's probably an edge case.